# java API to run sql script

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

What java API's are available to run a sql script. How do i get certain data read in the script -like count of processes accessing the database in the below script.

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @SPId int
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(100)

 SET @DatabaseName = N<dbname>

DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT SPId FROM MASTER..SysProcesses
WHERE DBId = DB_ID(@DatabaseName) AND SPId <> @@SPId

OPEN my_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @SPId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
 SET @SQL = 'KILL ' + CAST(@SPId as nvarchar(10))
 print @SQL
EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL


 FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @SPId
END

CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor 

GO

DROP DATABASE <dbname>
GO
```

Comment: Have you looked at JDBC?

Comment: I used the statement.execute(string) command by reading the file entries (delimitted by "GO"). But it gives the following error even the same thing runs in sql server mgmt studio.  java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'my_cursor'.
 at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)